# Deploy resources using Powershell DSC pull server

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to deploy Powershell modules from my https pull server but couldn't. I don't know what I'm missing here. These are things which I already did or tried:

1. Setup a https based pull server using instructions outlined at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/pullserver
2. Register a pull client using instructions mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/pullclientconfignames
3. On my pull server I've placed modules under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Modules as xWebAdministration_1.12.0.0.zip and xWebAdministration_1.12.0.0.zip.checksum

If I double click xWebAdministration_1.12.0.0.zip file it contains: DSCResources, Examples, Tests,  HighQualityResourceKitPlan.md, README.md and xWebAdministration.psd1 at root level, Under DSCResources I have all MSFT_* folders and other stuff

4. When I run a custom configuration on my client node which requires xWebAdministration module, I get module not found exception.

I looked at client's event viewer for errors but don't see anything related.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like pull server is not configured properly. Look into the Pull Server Logs to figure out what it is complaining about:                           Get-WinEvent –LogName "Microsoft-Windows-Powershell-DesiredStateConfiguration-PullServer/Operational"
Get-WinEvent –LogName "Microsoft-Windows-ManagementOdataService/Operational"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Publish-DSCModuleAndMof from xPSDesiredStateConfiguration?

You have to run `Install-Module xPSDesiredStateConfiguration` first.

You can find an example of using this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/pullserver#tooling).